# Use htaccess to redirect all traffic from root to specific subdomain page

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I have a site that has been up for some time.  I had a blog on a subdomain for some time.  I have decided to do away with the main site and just support the blog subdomain.

I have a redirect setup for this, but it carries all the extra parameters through to the blog which results in a file not found page appearing.  I just want the redirect to go to the index page without parameters.

What I currently have in my .htaccess file is this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/blog\.foo\.org\/index\.php" [R=301,L]
```

When I get a request to

http://www.foo.org/foo/foo/?module=foo

it redirects to

http://blog.foo.org/foo/foo/index.php?module=foo

I want it to redirect to 
http://blog.foo.org/index.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to specify the query in the replacement to override the original:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^blog\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://blog.example.org/index.php? [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://blog.foo.org/ [R=301,L]
```